How to get sum of all rows with column multiplication in canvas powerapps?
I have one table named InvoiceLines in SQL Server which has the following records.
InvoiceID    ProductDescription    Quantity    UnitRate
1            Tow Fee               2.00        217.39
1            Tow Fee               1.00        110.00

In my Canvas Power app(showing one label), I want a multiplication of Quantity and UnitRate and then a sum of all records that have InvoiceID as 1. So, in the text property, I have added this code.
LookUp(InvoiceLines, ThisItem.InvoiceID = InvoiceID,Sum(Quantity*UnitRate))

Where ThisItem.InvoiceID is 1. But it gives the result as 434.78. It took only the first records into consideration not second one. I want the result as 544.78. How can I do that in canvas app?

Lookup only gives back the first found result.
User filter instead.
Sum(Filter(Table, ColumnName = DesiredValue), Quantity * Unit Rate)

but it is giving "delegation warning. the "sum" part of this formula might not work correctly on large data sets." any work around to remove it?
